# How to write query for join two table in django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

Table1:

cam = models.CharField()

temp = models.Interger()

```
 id cam temp
 1   hi  10
 2   he   2
```

Table2:

cam = models.CharField()

count = models.Integer()

```
 cam count
  hi  5

select t2.count from Table2 t2 inner join Table1 t1 on t1.cam=t2.cam where t1.temp=10
```

Can anyone help to write the above query using django query.

Comment: where is your model??

Comment: Model name is Table1 and Table2

Comment: post your models with the fields, we need to understand if there is some relation or not

Comment: I have edited with models

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that your models `Table1` and `Table2` should be related, but, there is no relation in your code.

So, based entirely on your question description, solution should be like:

```
table1_cam_list = [c.cam for c in Table1.objects.filter(temp=10)]
table2_list = Table2.objects.filter(cam__in=table1_cam_list)
for item in table2_list:
    print(item.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to get the list of `cam` from `Table1` and you can use that list to filter from `Table2`.Although you should use [ForeginKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) field if you want a one-to-many relation in your database.

```
t1_cam_list=Table1.objects.filter(temp=10).values_list('cam', flat=True)
t2_list=Table2.objects.filter(cam__in=t1_cam_list).values_list('count',flat=True)
```